# Hibernate inserts duplicates after introducing base entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I tried to introduce a base entity to my Spring Boot application but now Hibernate inserts duplicate entries. The app uses Spring Data JPA and Hibernate for persistence.

My code before looked something like this:

```
@Entity
public class PasswordResetCode {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String code;

    public PasswordResetCode(User user, String code) {
        this.user = user;
        user.addPasswordResetCode(this);
        this.code = code;
    }

    // ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PasswordResetCode> passwordResetCodes = new HashSet<>();

    public void addPasswordResetCode(PasswordResetCode passwordResetCode) {
        this.passwordResetCodes.add(passwordResetCode);
    }

    // ...    
}
```

I create a PasswordResetCode like this:

```
User user = userRepository.findOne(id);
passwordResetCodeRepository.save(new PasswordResetCode(user, "some code"));
```

This works perfectly fine and the `PasswordResetCode` only gets inserted once into the database and the reference in the User objects `Set` gets updated with the persisted `PasswordResetCode`.

Now I introduced a `BaseEntity`, removed the id fields from the `User` and `PasswordReset` class and let them extend `BaseEntity`.
The `BaseEntity` looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id = 0;

    // getter & setter

}
```

I create the `PasswordResetCode` like before but now I get the following error because Hibernate tries to insert the code twice:

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];  constraint
>   ["UK_JIAB2A9LLEHA81LWDNYRL9RQ0_INDEX_2 ON
>   PUBLIC.PASSWORD_RESET_CODE(CODE) VALUES ('some code', 115)"

Now I realize that I can either remove the cascade in `User` or save the `PasswordResetCode` through the `User`/`UserRepository` but I want to understand what is happening.

Why can Hibernate see that the `PasswordResetCode` in the `User` set is the same that he saved through the repository although it gets added before it is persisted?
And why does it fail after the `BaseEntity` is added?

Answer (score 0):

I think user id is null refrence so hibernate create new one.

Comment: Makes sense but please elaborate beyond a one-liner, ( examples, refs etc ) so we can upvote :).

Comment: Where do the values of the user object come from? session ? or directly database ? or create a password change screen and use modelAttribute ? if user is model attribute and u use change form and send data with post method to controller user's id defined null becouse of create new  user instance

Comment: As I said, I realize what is happening after the introduction of the `BaseEntity`. `passwordResetCodeRepository.save` returns a new object that is now part of the persistence session. `User` is still referencing the old object that is not persisted (still has id = 0) and he hibernate creates a duplicate insert because of the cascade rule when he's persisting the user. My question is why the code worked before the introduction of `BaseEntity`, when the ids where defined in the entities.